# Add Custom Attribute in Customer Account admin side and its value from another Module?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, customer-attribute, custom-attributes, multiselect-attribute

I want to add a `multiselect dropdown attribute` to Customer module in Customer Account Tab (Admin Panel) and Want its value from my another module.

Please let me suggest how can I achieve this.

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: Customer module in Customer Account Tab ?? Where exactly front end or admin?

Comment: @Gopal, Admin side Customer Module's Customer Account Tab.

Answer (score 1):

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <YourCompany_YourModule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </YourCompany_YourModule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <yourmodule>
        <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Helper</class>
      </yourmodule>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <yourmodule>
        <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>yourmodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </yourmodule>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1480661105_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>YourCompany_YourModule</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1480661105_setup>
      <customerattribute1480661105_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1480661105_write>
      <customerattribute1480661105_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1480661105_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class YourCompany_YourModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

sql/customerattribute1480661105_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customer_attribute",  array(
    "type"     => "text",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Customer Attribute",
    "input"    => "multiselect",
    "source"   => "yourmodule/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions14806611050",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customer_attribute");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100)
        ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

Model/Eav/Entity/Attribute/Source/Customeroptions14806611050.php

```
<?php
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Customeroptions14806611050 extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
    //*******Here I have given sample values instead of this just retrieve your values in this format*******************
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("1"),
                    "value" =>  1
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("2"),
                    "value" =>  2
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("3"),
                    "value" =>  3
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("5"),
                    "value" =>  4
                ),

            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Column(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColums()
    {
        $columns = array();
        $columns[$this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode()] = array(
            "type"      => "tinyint(1)",
            "unsigned"  => false,
            "is_null"   => true,
            "default"   => null,
            "extra"     => null
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Indexes(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatIndexes()
    {
        $indexes = array();

        $index = "IDX_" . strtoupper($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        $indexes[$index] = array(
            "type"      => "index",
            "fields"    => array($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode())
        );

        return $indexes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Select For Flat Attribute update
     *
     * @param int $store
     * @return Varien_Db_Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel("eav/entity_attribute")
            ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

Create function to get all options of your another module and retrieve it in `function getAllOptions()` of given model.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and if works for me, I will accept it as a solution.